# Open link's content in slidedown fashion

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

As soon as I click on first list item, I want the mentioned link's content to get opened in slidedown fashion, not in the new window.I am new in Jquery Mobile, So I am not sure what's the correct way to do it..

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="http://www.tricksfind.in/2014/09/twitlonger-go-beyond-140-characters-in.html" data-transition="slidedown">Twitlonger:Go Beyond 140 Characters</a></li>
    <li><a href="scott.html">Scott Stroz</a></li>
    <li><a href="todd.html">Todd Sharp</a></li>
    <li><a href="dave.html">Dave Ferguson</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

[image]

Please suggest !!

Comment: "slidedown fashion" is ambiguous. Do you want a modal popup, a collapsible, accordion, etc.?  Please describe in more detail what you are looking for...

Comment: I will try to explain with example.. Please visit this site:https://www.yahoo.com/tech , if you click any of the link, it opens up in the same page, just the bottom of article heading..

Comment: you can use the popup widget: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/popup/. You can put an iframe inside it of use ajax to load page content. You can size it and position it and use slide transition.

Comment: Here is an example using the 3rd party jBox plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/d4x6cu31/1/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for the jquery mobile's collapsible widget. Refer to the link below.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/collapsible/